# How to authenticate users from res.users model in laradoo package

Tags: php, laravel, odoo

I have installed the `laradoo` package in my `Laravel` project, which will connect to odoo DB. I have made the connection to the DB but now I can't authenticate the users from the `res.users model`. because when I tried to fetch user information using the below code.

```
$odoo = new \Edujugon\Laradoo\Odoo();
$odoo = $odoo->connect();
$models = $odoo->where('login', 'test@test.com')->fields('name','login','password')->get('res.users');
echo "<pre>";
print_r($models);
```

it is giving the below response where the password is not returned.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => test
                    [login] => test@test.com
                    [password] => 
                )
         )
)
```

So, I have tried the other way around like create hash on Laravel and try to authenticate like the code below

```
$odoo = new \Edujugon\Laradoo\Odoo();

$odoo = $odoo->connect();
$password = "12345";
$iterations = 1000;

// Generate a random IV using openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()
// random_bytes() or another suitable source of randomness
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);

$hash = hash_pbkdf2("sha512", $password, $salt, $iterations, 20);

$models = $odoo->where('login', 'test@test.com')->where('password', $hash)->fields('name','login','password')->get('res.users');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($models);
```

but it is not working properly. it will always return to the user if the password is right or wrong. so, if you could help me in fetching passwords from odoo or creating a hash for odoo `res.users model` would be great.

Comment: you cant get hashed password it is security reason, Check what $oddo responsing when you use connect()

Comment: @NurbekBoymurodov can I create a hash in laravel and authenticate users on odoo side? the  connection has been made

Answer (score 0):

If you need to override laravel hashing for accepting passwords from odoo DB. You need to modify the following function as per your need for hashing in EloquentUserProvider.php

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        $hash = hash('sha512',$plain);
        if($hash == $user->getAuthPassword() ){
            return true;

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    
        // return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
```